# graph with prinicple amount and interest

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need of making a graph between interest, principle and year. From webservices I am getting following values

```
[
    {
        "Year": 1,
        "beginbal": 230000,
        "endbal": 223725.97,
        "interestY": 559.31,
        "paymentY": 13088.23
    }, {
        "Year": 2,
        "beginbal": 223725.97,
        "endbal": 217261.1,
        "interestY": 543.15,
        "paymentY": 13088.23
    }, {
        "Year": 3,
        "beginbal": 217261.1,
        "endbal": 210599.6,
        "interestY": 526.5,
        "paymentY": 13088.23
    }, {
        "Year": 4,
        "beginbal": 210599.6,
        "endbal": 203735.49,
        "interestY": 509.34,
        "paymentY": 13088.23
    }, {
        "Year": 5,
        "beginbal": 203735.49,
        "endbal": 196662.59,
        "interestY": 491.66,
        "paymentY": 13088.23
    }, {
        "Year": 6,
        "beginbal": 196662.59,
        "endbal": 189374.57,
        "interestY": 473.44,
        "paymentY": 13088.23
    }, {
        "Year": 7,
        "beginbal": 189374.57,
        "endbal": 181864.88,
        "interestY": 454.66,
        "paymentY": 13088.23
    }, {
        "Year": 8,
        "beginbal": 181864.88,
        "endbal": 174126.77,
        "interestY": 435.32,
        "paymentY": 13088.23
    }, {
        "Year": 9,
        "beginbal": 174126.77,
        "endbal": 166153.3,
        "interestY": 415.38,
        "paymentY": 13088.23
    }, {
        "Year": 10,
        "beginbal": 166153.3,
        "endbal": 157937.3,
        "interestY": 394.84,
        "paymentY": 13088.23
    }
]
```

[image]

I have to make the graph between balance amount and year with the gap of 5. Year 5 .. year 10. But I am unable to find the way that how to start implementing graph with above values. If anyone get some idea about the graph please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to use some sort of graphing library?  What have you actually tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Core Plot [coreplot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/).  It can graph all sorts of info.  You will want to put you web info into an array as Core Plot uses arrays to graph. Good luck. They have plenty of examples as well on the website.

Comment: it is showing nothing under core plot. Can you add the link again?

Comment: @MinkleGarg,  sorry about that.  I have edited my answer.  The link should work now.